# Text to Column (VBA) Issue

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Any idea why I'm getting an error message on the below code, I'm trying to seperate 3/4 into two columns containing 3 and 4 respectively;

The error message I get is;
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Sub Test()
'Pause "Cell Contains a Value" Message Error
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Perform text to columnn function
Sheets("Look Up Tables").Range("Text_to_Columns").TextToColumns _
    Destination:=Sheets("Look Up Tables").Range("AE16:AF:16"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:="/"

'Resume "Cell Contains a Value" Error Message
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: `Range("AE16:AF:16")` - is this a typo in your code or just when you copied the code into the question?

Comment: No typo (unless you spot something I've missed), the destination range is deep within the spreadsheet so cells AE16 & AF16 are correct

Comment: Error message as described in body of message above the code; Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: What @FunThomas is saying that you have a typo.. an extra ":" in `"AE16:AF:16"`. It should be `"AE16:AF16"`

Comment: `AE16:AF:16` is not a valid address for a range.

Comment: Thank you!!! Couldn't see the bloody wood through the trees, had been stairing at that code for an hour, clearly needed outside perspective

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the obvious answer is that the definition of the destination range has an extra `:` and therefore is invalid - the correct syntax is `Range("AE16:AF16")`

It helps to split such long commands into pieces:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Look Up Tables")
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destRange as Range
    Set sourceRange = .Range("Text_to_Columns")
    Set destrange = .Range("AE16:AF:16")   ' <-- Error is here
    sourceRange.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=destRange _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="/"
End With
```

Now you will get the runtime error before the `TextToColumns`-command is executed and it gets much easier to catch the problem. And no, execution is not slower.